# SQL subquery insert error

Tags: sql, insert

I'm trying to insert a value into a table, but based on the value of Webtype, but I'm getting errors.

```
INSERT INTO GS_WEBSITES_LIVE (THIS_MONTH) 
( SELECT 
    COUNT ( DISTINCT LPL.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_KEY ) AS THIS_MONTH
FROM 
    BW_SHARE.LP_LIVE_MAY16 LPL    
WHERE 
    LPL.MATERIAL = 'ECOM'
)
WHERE WEBTYPE = 'WEB';
```

Comment: And the error is? But you can't have two `where` clauses for single select statement. (and `insert` doesn't have a `where` part)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery has no column called `WEBTYPE`, which is the direct cause of the error.  So, you may want this:

```
INSERT INTO GS_WEBSITES_LIVE (THIS_MONTH) 
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT LPL.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_KEY ) AS THIS_MONTH
    FROM BW_SHARE.LP_LIVE_MAY16 LPL    
    WHERE LPL.MATERIAL = 'ECOM' AND WEBTYPE = 'WEB';
```

However, I suspect you want an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE GS_WEBSITES_LIVE
    SET THIS_MONTH = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LPL.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_KEY ) AS THIS_MONTH
                      FROM BW_SHARE.LP_LIVE_MAY16 LPL    
                      WHERE LPL.MATERIAL = 'ECOM'
                     )
    WHERE WEBTYPE = 'WEB';
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you all for your help, update worked perfectly.